# When/how to write data in redis cache to SQL database?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, caching, redis

I have a fairly small relational database currently setup (SQLite, changing to PostgreSQL) that has some relatively simple many-to-one and many-to-many relations. The app uses Websockets to give real-time updates to any clients so I want to make any operations as quick as possible. I was planning on using redis to cache parts of the data in memory as required (parts that will be read/written frequently) so that queries will be faster. I know with the database currently so small, performance gains aren't going to be noticeable but I want it to be scalable.

There seems to be a lot of material/information suggesting using redis as a cache is a good idea, but I'm struggling to find much information about when it is suitable to write updates to the SQL database and how is best to do it.

For example, should I write updates to the redis-store, then send updated data out to clients and then write the same update to the SQL database all in the same request (in that order)? (i.e. more frequent smaller writes)

Or should I simply just write updates to the redis-store and send the updated data out to clients. Then, periodically (every minute?) read back from the redis-store and subsequently save it in the SQL database? (i.e. less frequent but larger writes)

Or is there some other best practice for keeping a redis store and SQL database consistent?
Would my first example perform poorly due to the larger number of writes to disk and the CPU being more active or would this be negligible?

Comment: Look`s like you want something like http://hedis.io/ - a caching layer between your application and your database backend by Redis

Comment: @misterion Thanks, looks promising. Will take a look at it.

Comment: @myles did you get any solution to your problem?